# Two activities are created when I try to create a new Blank Activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Whenever I try to create a new blank activity in the layout folder two layouts are created.For eg:When I try to create a Blank Activity by name lola following two activities are created i.e. activity_lolla.xml and content_lolla.xml:

[image]

[image: Two Activities]

Comment: `where is your question?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not two activities, but two layout files... U can use "Empty Activity" template to avoid that. In this case you also would add android:label="@string/title_of_your_new_activity" in the manifest file ander activity node

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make an assumption that you are either:

A)Just beginning to learn Android from tutorials that uses older version of Android Studio

B)Recently upgraded to new Android Studio 1.4

If you look at activity_lola.xml, you should see in middle, there should be a line of code like this:

`<include layout="@layout/content_lola" />`

Both of these are layout files but only activity_lola is considered an activity. The content_lola is layout that is included inside the activity_lola.

So basically if you belong to assumption A, you can get the "Blank Activity" that books and other tutorials are referring to by selecting "Empty Activity".

Hope this helps and happy coding! =P